# org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to run a program.  Without testng it works fine.  But when I ran using TestNG  it works smoothly all the login scenarios but when it comes to logout XPath it says

```
FAILED: Testloginpager
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: The xpath expression '//a[contains(text(),'Log out')]' cannot be evaluated or does notresult in a WebElement (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 5.19 seconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/invalid_selector_exception.html
```

But I tried the same XPath in Mozilla and found that it is the right path for that logout web element.

Comment: Post your code! Chances are you have unbalanced or misplaced quotes.

Answer (score 0):

It might be the quotes?

I don't use xPath, so I haven't experienced this, but maybe try double quotes `"` instead of the single.

Or you could try this:

Instead of `By.xpath()`.  Use:

```
By.linkText("Log out");
```

Comment: XPath does it like JavaScript and Python: you can put a string in double or single quotes.